# Dynamic read value from field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        alert($("input:text").val());
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

Firstname: <input type="text" name="fname" value="Peter"><br>
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Griffin"><br><br>

<button>Return the value of the first input field</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like instead of running the function on button click, to run it and display value from the first field dynamically and f.e. in the content of the website instead of popup.

How can I achieve that?
Thanks in advance for your tips and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if want the function to get fired "dynamically", `keyup()` might be what to want. It fires the function every time the user releases a key on their keyboard while typing in your first input field.

To show the value of your input field on the site itself and not in a popup, use jQuerys `text()` method. In this example, I added a `div` for the output, otherwise the sites content would get messed up because we would replace the sites content with the value of your input field.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input:text').keyup(function() {
        $('#result').text(($("input:text").val()));
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  Firstname: <input type="text" name="fname" value="Peter"><br> Lastname: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Griffin"><br><br>

  <button>Return the value of the first input field</button>
  <div id="result"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `onkeyup` event handler

```js
function showInputVal(elem) {
  $("#inputDisplay").text(elem.value)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Firstname: <input type="text" onkeyup="showInputVal(this)" name="fname" value="Peter">
<br> Lastname: <input type="text" onkeyup="showLastNameVal(this)" name="lname" value="Griffin">

<br><br>

<div id="inputDisplay"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed it's the solution for my case ;)